# Prove that $AC^2 + BD^2+ 4PQ^2 = AB^2 +BC^2+ CA^2+DA^2$

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

In a quadrilateral $ABCD$ in which $P$ and $Q$ are the midpoints of $AC$ and $BD$. Prove that $AC^2 + BD^2+ 4PQ^2 = AB^2 +BC^2+ CA^2+DA^2$

Please help me with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Use the formula for the midline in triangles $QAC, ABD, CBD$

Comment: I tried to solve this problem so I defined $R$ in the middle of $QA$, $S$ in the middle of $AB$ and $T$ in the middle of $CB$, so I have these equations to play with $2PR=QC$, $2QS = AD$ and $2QT = CD$. That seems to just introduce more variables so I'm stuck.

Comment: @totembowl $P$ is the middle of $AC$. So $QP$ is a midline in the triangle $QAC$. You don't need $R,S$!

Comment: Could the problem be that I drew the quadrilateral wrong? My vertices are, in clockwise order: $ACDB$. I couldn't put them as $ABCD$ because I need $A$ next to $C$ to put $P$.

Comment: @totembowl Yes. The quadrilater must be in the order $ABCD$. $P,Q$ are the midpoints of the diagonals, not of the edges....

Comment: Thanks, but if I try the quadrilateral you describe, then I don't see how $QP$ can be the midline in the triangle $QAC$ because $Q$ is a vertex in that triangle. If I assume you meant that the $AQ$ segment should be prolonged so that $Q$ is in the middle of that segment, then I don't see where the terminal point should be. Just in case I'm really confused, this is what you mean by [midline theorem](http://regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp10/midlinel.htm), right?

Comment: @totembowl By midline I mean the line which connects the vertex to the midpoint of the opposite edge. I think the english word is median.